# Cannot connect to VPN via remote desktop - CISCO AnyConnect client

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

I am remote controlling the window server 2012, then I need  to use `Cisco anyConnect Secure Mobility Client` to connect my client's VPN. However, there have a problem when I am trying to connect the VPN:

> VPN establishment capability from a remote desktop is disabled.  A VPN connection will not be established.

However, I can connect the VPN on my local PC.

How can I connect to the VPN in this situation? Do it need to config by the VPN owner or I have some mistake with the client side config?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to check for open ports. If your server goes through a firewall to connect to the world, Windows may use different ports depending on the VPN protocol you are using.

Here's one Technet entry discussing appropriate ports to open https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/0fff3b48-7615-45ea-817e-5afaad972c43/vpn-ports-to-open?forum=winservergen.

And this Stack Exchange thread covers Windows 2008 R2: https://serverfault.com/questions/238903/ports-needed-open-for-windows-vpn